# How to execute a Stored Procedure with NCommon and EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework-4, domain-driven-design, ncommon

I'm using NCommon for DDD layer and Entity Framework.

I would like to execute a Stored Procedure but not sure how you go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can map stored procedures in EF4. It supports it. Just Add required stored proc in designer and use associated function in your code.